# C++ set sorting with pair as key

Tags: c++, sorting, set, std-pair

How will an ordered set container in c++ sort its keys if the key is a pair? (By default without a custom comparator)

Say I have a key of (1,2) and another key of (1,1).

Am I right to say that it will try to sort with respect to the first value in the pair then if they are equal proceed to compare the second pair value ?

So in this scenario (1,1) will be before (1,2).

Comment: You may create your own ordering, if that's what you're asking

Comment: *"Am I right to say that it will try to sort with respect to the first value in the pair then if their equal proceed to compare the second pair value?"* [Yes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp).

Comment: It will by default user operator< for std::pair

Comment: Doesn't it use `std::less`, @MaLarsson? And doesn't it use that default for any key type? Yes, that boils down to using `operator <` for many types, but it's not the same.

Comment: Ah, yes @UlrichEckhardt, you're right. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the way the keys in set/map (and their multi variants) are sorted using a template parameter. This template parameter is not always given, because it has defaults. It is only required if there is not default sorting order or that order isn't right for the use case. However, this is also what you need to look at: It's the template parameter default and what that default means for pairs which determines how they are sorted.

Long story short, a lexical comparison is used, comparing the first and then the second element. Of course, this again used defaults, because the first half of a pair can be a pair itself etc.

Comment: So by default it compares with the first element of the pair then moves on to the second element if they are the same right ?

Comment: True, that's basically the definition of a lexical comparison. Anyhow, you could check out Vlad's answer above, he even quoted the precise definition while I would have left that bit of research to you. With that definition, you can fill in various values to see for yourself whether it fits what you expected.

Comment: True, that's basically the definition of a lexical comparison. Anyhow, you could check out Vlad's answer above, he even quoted the precise definition while I would have left that bit of research to you. With that definition, you can fill in various values to see for yourself whether it fits what you expected.

Answer (score 4):

The template class `std::pair` has already the defined `operator <`. So you can sort containers that contain objects of the type `std::pair`.

From the C++ Standard (20.3.3 Specialized algorithms)

```
template <class T1, class T2>
constexpr bool operator<(const pair<T1, T2>& x, const pair<T1, T2>& y);
```

> 2 Returns: x.first < y.first || (!(y.first < x.first) && x.second <
>   y.second).

Also you can consider two objects as members of an object of the type `std::pair` using function `std::tie`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::pair<int, int> a[] = { { 1, 2 }, { 1, 1 } };

    for ( const auto &p : a ) 
    {
        std::cout << "< " << p.first << ", " << p.second << "> ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );

    for ( const auto &p : a ) 
    {
        std::cout << "< " << p.first << ", " << p.second << "> ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    struct Pair
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    } b[] = { { 1, 2 }, { 1, 1 } };

    for ( const auto &p : b ) 
    {
        std::cout << "< " << p.x << ", " << p.y << "> ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( std::begin( b ), std::end( b ), 
        []( const Pair &left, const Pair &right)
        {
            return std::tie( left.x, left.y ) < std::tie( right.x, right.y );
        } );

    for ( const auto &p : b ) 
    {
        std::cout << "< " << p.x << ", " << p.y << "> ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
< 1, 2> < 1, 1> 
< 1, 1> < 1, 2> 

< 1, 2> < 1, 1> 
< 1, 1> < 1, 2>
```